# Half my house disappeared for no reason at all why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I was playing normally, and for fun I went to the nether in creative. I spent about half a Minecraft day there and when I returned I went to my house. I realised that I couldn't see the other half of my house. I went to the other side and I just saw half of my house cut off. It was like a cliff and when I flew to the edge of it all I could see was the inside of my house and a lot of stone. The sky sort of went black and I couldn't fly up or down I was stuck there. And at that moment I heard music playing. Weird music.

If you have experienced this and know a solution, can you please give me any suggestions on how to solve this problem as I am sort of freaked out...

Comment: Did it work after you restarted Minecraft?

Answer (score 12):

### What the Problem is

This is most likely a chunk glitch, basically the game froze up somewhat and didn't render in a chunk. This usually happens when in Creative or Spectator because you are moving much faster than you can in survival.

It's more common on multiplayer than single player because the server (even if you're connected via LAN, it's still a server) has to do more and there's *way* more chance for the server and client to get out of sync.

### Solutions:

There are a few things you can do.

1. Quickest/easiest thing to do, would to press <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. This will force the game to reload all of the chunks and should fix this visual glitch.
2. If that doesn't fix it, try leaving the game and coming back in - that will totally reload all the chunks.

### Explanation:

As for why you got stuck, you probably flew into where the server knew there were blocks, and then your client halfway caught up.

The server knew where you were and that you were in a block(s) and so told your client that you couldn't move, expecting your client to know this from information that it *should* have received earlier about your location/that chunk.

However, since your client most likely didn't receive that information earlier, it just stops you from moving.

As for the music, that's just part of the game - music randomly selected from a list at certain times of the day. [See here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Music) for more information.

Comment: I've had this happen on a Terraria server. Wierd to be digging and then have a huge square part of the world just empty - or have half my "house" missing. Quit/reload always worked. It seemed like the server just didn't have the juice needed and would ever-so-periodically choke sending me a "chunk".